# Can't open .ics files with react native if app is in closed state initially

Tags: android, react-native, filesystems, icalendar, intentfilter

I want to share with you, a problem I have with my react native app, I'm struggling with this error and I really can't find a solution yet.

**Context**: I created a calendar app, where you can create meetings and invite friends. You have a personal calendar with hours and days, similar to Teams. The app also allows to open .ics files and add its content as a meeting inside my app. (Backend does this logic, I only read the file and send its content to my backend).

**Technologies**: Expo 46, ejected app.

**Problem**: (Android only) I want my app to be able to open .ics files from other apps like Samsung Email, Gmail, Whatsapp and so on WHEN my app is in CLOSED and OPEN state, so for example, you receive an .ics file in an email and when you press on it my app should appear in the suggested list of apps to open that file.
I managed to achieve that, modifing my AndroidManifiest.xml adding the corresponding intent-filter.

Now, the problem is: If my app is CLOSED and I go to the third party app and try to open the .ics file with my app, my app opens, BUT it cannot open the .ics file, this error is shown on the console (If opening an .ics file from Samsung Email using my app):
[Error: Permission Denial: opening provider com.samsung.android.email.provider.provider.attachment.AttachmentPreviewProvider from ProcessRecord{ac4a696 12511:com.xxxx.xxxx/xxxxx} (pid=xxxxx, uid=xxxxx) requires com.samsung.android.email.permission.ACCESS_PROVIDER or com.samsung.android.email.permission.ACCESS_PROVIDER]

When opening an .ics file from WhatsApp using my app:
[Error: Permission Denial: opening provider com.whatsapp.contentprovider.MediaProvider from ProcessRecord{2f5dde 20320:com.xxxxx.xxxxx/xxxxx} (pid=xxxxx, uid=xxxx) that is not exported from UID xxxxxx]

I replaced sensitive information with "xxxxx".

BUT, when my app is OPEN and I navigate to the third party app and try to open the .ics file with my app, IT WORKS!

It's necessary that my app manages to open the .ics if it's CLOSED initially.

I don't know how to continue or proceed with this case, any help will be very well received.

Thanks community!

I tested several libraries for opening files, I used react-native-fs, react-native-blob-util and also I coded a native module for Android to read the file as a stream and pass the info to the Javascript side.. also same error.